# How to change the parent of DataContext in xaml in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

I have this xaml in windows phone 8.1. 
My page data context is binded to a ViewModel, i.e. VM.
And My listView is binded to Items of ViewModel.
And the text in each list view item is binded to Text of Items of ViewModel.

```
<Page DataContext="{Binding VM}">
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding soemthing in VM}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Page>
```

My question is how can I change the parent datacontext of my 2nd TextBox so that I can bind something in my ViewModel (not my ViewModel.Items)?

Thank you.

Comment: Basically, you can't -- WP Silverlight does not support RelativeSource `Mode=FindAncestor`, unfortunately.  Have to use a workaround.  What are you trying to bind to? (string? brush? another collection?)

Comment: You could always use dependency injection. Inject a reference to the binding you actually want into the Item ViewModel

Comment: I am tryin to bind to a RelayCommand in my ViewModel. AFAIK, RelayCommand should be in ViewModel, so I can't put that in my Items.

Comment: How to use dependency injection for binding it to view model?

Comment: That means, pass a reference to the RelayCommand into each item, and expose it as a property -- then you can bind to it.  It's not ideal, but may be the best option.

Comment: An alternative might be to make the RelayCommand a static resource on the page, and bind to it that way.  That is tricky though, because you can end up with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Element Binding,

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>


            <!-- Bind the DataContext directly to the whatever element you like, in this case the page, then the Text Binding is basically the DataContext.VM_Property -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.VM_Property}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=page}" ></TextBlock>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```